# Creating table out of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation, csv-format

I have two lists:

```
fi = { -0.25, -0.21 , -0.1, ...}
fv = { 2, 3, 4, ...}
```

Now I want to export these in form of a CSV file, which should look like this:

```
-0.25, 2, -0.21, 3, -0.1, 4
```

But when I used `Export[filename, {fv,fi}]` the file looks like this

```
-0.25, -0.21, -0.1, 2, 3, 4
```

I tried formatting the two lists into a Table and Grid but I can't get the syntax right.

Comment: If they're the same length, `Riffle[fi, fv]`.

Comment: you can use Riffle[{fi}, {fv}] // Transpose // Flatten, check but the lenth of each list

Comment: do you really want all the data on one row?  maybe just `Export["file.csv",Transpose@{fi, fv}]` makes more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[`Riffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html)**

```
Riffle[Range[10], CharacterRange["a", "j"]]
```

> ```
> {1, "a", 2, "b", 3, "c", 4, "d", 5, "e", 6, "f", 7, "g", 8, "h", 9, "i", 10, "j"}
> ```

**[`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)**

```
Flatten@Transpose@{Range[10], CharacterRange["a", "j"]}
```

> ```
> {1, "a", 2, "b", 3, "c", 4, "d", 5, "e", 6, "f", 7, "g", 8, "h", 9, "i", 10, "j"}
> ```

**[`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)** (Thanks @J.M.)

```
Flatten[{Range[10], CharacterRange["a", "j"]}, {{2, 1}}]
```

Beware of the behaviour of `Riffle` if the lists are not the same length.

```
 Riffle[Range[10], CharacterRange["a", "z"]]
```

> ```
> {1, "a", 2, "b", 3, "c", 4, "d", 5, "e", 6, "f", 7, "g", 8, "h", 9, "i", 10}
> ```

### Performances

```
First@RepeatedTiming[
  Riffle[Range[999], CharacterRange[1, 999]]
  , 9]
(* 0.00060 *)

First@RepeatedTiming[
  Flatten@Transpose@{Range[999], CharacterRange[1, 999]}
  , 9]
(* 0.00076 *)

First@RepeatedTiming[
  Flatten[{Range[999], CharacterRange[1, 999]}, {{2, 1}}]
  , 9]
(* 0.00065 *)
```

Comment: You can skip `Transpose[]` altogether and just use `Flatten[]`: `Flatten[{Range[10], CharacterRange["a", "j"]}, {{2, 1}}]`.

Comment: Thanks now it is working :) However when i want to export the file with `Export[filename , Riffle[fv,fi]` , "CSV"] the commas are not in the file?

Comment: @TheCheatsrichter
What comas?
You asked for a single column!
Probably you want  `Export["file.csv",Transpose@{fi, fv}]` as pointed out by @george2079

Comment: Exactly what i wanted! Tried this for 3 hours now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TheCheatsrichter, well that is not what you ask for in your question.